# How to define CoreData relationship in Swift?

Tags: core-data, swift, ios8

In CoreData, I have defined an unordered to-many relationship from `Node` to `Tag`. I've created an Swift entity like this:

```
import CoreData
class Node : NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var tags : Array<Tag>
}
```

Now I want to add a `Tag` to an instance of `Node`, like this:

```
var node = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Node", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as Node
node.tags.append(tag)
```

However, this fails with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "tags"; desired type = **NSSet**; given type = _TtCSs22ContiguousArrayStorage000000000B3440D4; value = (
>       "<_TtC8MotorNav3Tag: 0xb3437b0> (entity: Tag; id: 0xb343800  ; data: {...})"
>   ).'

What is the correct type for to-many relationships?

Comment: NSSet is not available in Swift? where did you find that?

Comment: Also the error message indicates that the relationship is *ordered*, not unordered.

Comment: @BryanChen ah yes, your comment made me realize that NSSet is available through `Foundation`.

Comment: @MartinR I've copied the error message where it was still defined as ordered set.

Comment: @bouke: The error message still mentions ".. value for *ordered* to-many relationship". Could you please copy/paste the actual error message into the question, to avoid confusion of future readers?

Comment: @MartinR good idea; updated the post accordingly.

Comment: As boule points out below, relationships in CoreData are sets, not arrays.

Comment: For others that find this question because they want to learn how to use relations in Core Data, i finally found this tutorial: [Core Data and Swift: Relationships and More Fetching](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-relationships-and-more-fetching--cms-25070)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To be able to work with one-to-many relationship in Swift you need to define property as:

```
class Node: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var tags: NSSet
}
```

If you try to use `NSMutableSet` changes will not be saved in CoreData. And of course it is recommended to define reverse link in `Node`:

```
class Tag: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var node: Node
}
```

But still Swift cannot generate dynamic accessors in runtime, so we need to define them manually. It is very convenient to define them in class `extension` and put in `Entity+CoreData.swift` file. Bellow is content of `Node+CoreData.swift` file:

```
extension Node {
    func addTagObject(value:Tag) {
        var items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("tags");
        items.addObject(value)
    }

    func removeTagObject(value:Tag) {
        var items = self.mutableSetValueForKey("tags");
        items.removeObject(value)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// somewhere before created/fetched node and tag entities
node.addTagObject(tag)
```

**Important:** To make it all work you should verify that class names of entities in you CoreData model includes your module name. E.g. `MyProjectName.Node`

Comment: Hey Keenie, When I use your extension I get the error: `"'NSSet' does not have a member named 'addTagObject'"`. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @Pirijan, you must be invoking addTagObject method on tags: NSSet property while you should invoke it on the object that has tags property.

Comment: Thanks Keenle, I couldn't figure it out so I posted a more thorough question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127090/saving-coredata-to-many-relationships-in-swift

Comment: Thanks, although later posted, your answer is more complete and I reward you for that :).

Comment: This did not work for me. After calling the remove function on the parent of the to-many relationship, the attempt to save failed because the child still existed but its required relationship to its parent was nil.

Answer (score 12):

As of Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0, the [release note](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html) 17583057 states:

> The NSManaged attribute can be used with methods as well as
>   properties, for access to Core Data’s automatically generated
>   Key-Value-Coding-compliant to-many accessors.

```
@NSManaged var employees: NSSet

@NSManaged func addEmployeesObject(employee: Employee)
@NSManaged func removeEmployeesObject(employee: Employee)
@NSManaged func addEmployees(employees: NSSet)
@NSManaged func removeEmployees(employees: NSSet)
```

> These can be declared in your NSManagedObject subclass. (17583057)

So you just have to declare the following methods and CoreData will take care of the rest:

```
@NSManaged func addTagsObject(tag: Tag)
@NSManaged func removeTagsObject(tag: Tag)
@NSManaged func addTags(tags: NSSet)
@NSManaged func removeTags(tags: NSSet)
```

Answer (score 11):

Actually you can just define:

```
@NSManaged var employees: Set<Employee>
```

And use the `insert` and `remove` methods of the `Set` directly.

Comment: Have you checked this actually work? If you save the model after having modified the employees set this way, will the modifications actually be saved?

Comment: I'm actually using this approach in this very same moment and it's working.

Comment: Interesting! I did not know it was possible. Apple should really clarify the Core Data/Swift usage I think…

Comment: Are there common cases where the set should be an Optional? Or is it best to define it as in your example?

Comment: I use it just for *Non Ordered*, *Non Optional*, *To Many*, with *Cascade* delete rule, relationships, which happen to be the most common cases (at least in my code). If you mark your model relationship as *Optional* then it should be `Set<Employee>?`

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. I find that a lot of Core Data information is couched in Objective-C conventions, so Swift-specific explanations are much appreciated.

Comment: This is probably only possible in iOS 10 because of the improvements to Core Data, but it is much much better than the other, older options

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Keenle's answer, if you want to be cheeky and concise and be able to say

```
node.tags.append(tag)
```

one can wrap the call to self.mutableSetValueForKey:

```
class Node: NSManagedObject {

    var tags: NSMutableOrderedSet {
        return self.mutableOrderedSetValueForKey("tags")
    }
}
```